# Equal-size categories vs unequal-size categories

Tags: classification, categorical-data, data-transformation

I'm trying to reduce the size of my dataset, which is composed of 200,000 projects. Each project is defined by its size and a binary value that is 1 if the project has active users, 0 otherwise. Most of the project sizes are < 1000 (80% of the dataset).

I would like to group the projects, and for each group I would count the number of projects with active users.

I'm not sure how to group these projects. In particular, is it better to group the projects into categories with equal intervals (0-500, 501-1000, 1001-1500, ...) or into categories with the same number of projects (as a consequence, I would have unequal intervals like 0-10, 11-15, 16-40, 41-100, 101-120, ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leave the **data** as they are. 200,000 is not an enormous data size for anyone, unless the problem is that they need a decent computer. Not changing the dataset keeps all the detail and stops you discarding information that might be interesting or useful.

That still leaves the question of appropriate interval size for those **specific occasions when a reduction is needed for display**, as say for histograms or tabulations. Irregular size intervals are just puzzling to many readers (especially those better informed technically) and raise the question of what is a property of the data and what a side-effect of arbitrary choices.

A compromise could be to use intervals that are (at least approximately) equal-sized on a logarithmic scale, e.g. 1, 2, 3-4, 5-8, 9-16, etc. or possibly equal-sized on a square root scale. Logarithms and square roots are the most useful transformations for highly skewed data such as these.

(Detail: I remain unclear where project size **is** number of users, or something else.)

Comment: thanks for answering, I'll try to one of the transformations you suggest. The project size is the number of KBs of a project

Comment: $\lfloor \log_k \text{size}\rfloor$ will give you classes in one step, for some $k$,